# Memory inspection using cuda Nsight debugger

Tags: cuda, nsight

[image]

In the [above screenshot of NSIGHT debugger](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/debugging_cuda_application.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25204.1%7CCUDA%2520Debugger%7C_____1), can some one explain me:

1- What exactly is 0.2010854? (See Local window)

2- What is the value at the address: 0x00110000

3- Why is this address only 16 bits? On a 32 bit OS, should it not be 32 bit? 
Sorry it was my mistake, it is 32 bit as pointed out in the comment below.

Comment: I think 0.2010854 is the first `float` value pointed to by the `__device__ float*` pointer referenced on that line (`A`).  What makes you think `0x00110000` is a 16 bit address?  Each hexadecimal digit requires 4 bits of storage.  There are 8 hexadecimal digits shown.  4x8=32 bits.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, oh yes, its 32 bit. BTW what info is given by Memory window? Is there 0.2010854 in that window?

Comment: The memory window also shows you what is stored in memory starting at the memory address `0x00110000` (in this case), but it shows you the data byte-by-byte.  For example,  if you took the first 4 bytes and rearranged them into a 32-bit quantity (so, `0x3e4de99c`) you would have the `float` representation of 0.2010854.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1- What exactly is 0.2010854? (See Local window)

It is the `float` quantity contained at the address 0x00110000  We expect a `float` representation, because the variable `A`, a `__device__` `float` pointer, should be pointing to a `float` quantity:

```
A = 0x00110000

*A = 0.2010854
```

> 2- What is the value at the address: 0x00110000

The value at that address is 0.2010854 expressed as a `float` quantity, or 0x3e4de99c expressed as a 32-bit hexadecimal quantity (e.g. hexadecimal unsigned integer).

> 3- Why is this address only 16 bits? On a 32 bit OS, should it not be 32 bit? Sorry it was my mistake, it is 32 bit as pointed out in the comment below.

The address is actually 32 bits.  Each hexadecimal digit constitutes 4 bits, and there are 8 digits.

> what info is given by Memory window? Is there 0.2010854 in that window?

The memory window also shows you what is stored in memory starting at the memory address 0x00110000 (in this case), but it shows you the data byte-by-byte. For example, if you took the first 4 bytes and rearranged them into a 32-bit quantity (so, 0x3e4de99c) you would have the float representation of 0.2010854.